# Java counter is off---Not like anything I've seen here yet

Tags: java, counter

The counter for pass or fail is backwards. It uses a sentinel and counts fails and  passes. Only it is counting in reverse. If you enter a passing grade it adds it to fails, etc. This is total code:

I just edited it...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PassOrFail1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total;
        int gradeCounter;
        int grade;
        double average;

        int passes = 0;
        int fails = 0;
        int studentCounter = 0;

        total = 0;
        gradeCounter = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter a grade");
        grade = input.nextInt();

        while (grade != 000) {

            total = total + grade;
            gradeCounter++;
            studentCounter++;
            System.out.println("Enter a grade");
            grade = input.nextInt();

            if( grade >= 70 ){
                passes++;
            }
            else
            {
                fails++;
            }

        }
        if(gradeCounter != 0){
            average = (double)total/gradeCounter;
            System.out.printf("The average for the grades is %.2f\nGradeCounter is %11d",average,gradeCounter);
        }
        System.out.printf("\nNumber of Passes is %7d \nNumber of Fails is %8d\nand number of students is %d", passes, fails, studentCounter);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do that for me.  What inputs are you giving and what outputs are you getting? What did you expect to get for those inputs?

Comment: When you step through in a debugger, what are the runtime values when this happens?  It also seems a little strange that you prompt for a second grade without ever adding the first one to the passes/fails counters.

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't add the terminating `-1` to the number of failing grades.

Comment: I input 90, 90, 50. I just edited it and I still get 3 grades counted, 2 fails, 1 pass and 3 students counted. Just like the following: </b>The average for the grades is 76.67
GradeCounter is           3
Number of Passes is       1 
Number of Fails is        2
and number of students is 3he following:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this code instead >>> !

[image: Code Run]
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class PassOrFail {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int total;
int gradeCounter;
int grade;
double average;

int passes = 0;
int fails = 0;
int studentCounter = 0;

total = 0;
gradeCounter = 0;

System.out.println("Enter a grade");
grade = input.nextInt();

while (grade != -1) {

    total = total + grade;
    gradeCounter++;
    studentCounter++;
    if( grade >=70 ){
        passes++;
    }
    else
    {
        fails++;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a grade");
    grade = input.nextInt();


}
if(gradeCounter != 0){
    average = (double)total/gradeCounter;
    System.out.printf("The average for the grades is %.2f\n GradeCounter is %d",average,gradeCounter);
}
System.out.printf("\nNumber of Passes is %d \n Number of Fails is %d ", passes, fails);
}
}
```